# Displaying SVG elements with D3 and d3.slider: Uncaught TypeError: .exit is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am using this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/cmdoptesc/fc0e318ce7992bed7ca8) in D3.js as my start point and I wanted to do the same thing as in this example. With the help of stackoverflow I could already learn alot about D3 but now I'm stuck with a problem I don't understand. My code is on this [repo](https://github.com/RitterLean/Slider-geojson-testing) because I don't know yet (?) how to share with you my files without wasting to much space. I get an error when I move the slider back and forth. The movement to the right will spawn points but they won't disappear when the slider is moved to the left what they are doing in the example. Also I am not sure if they always spawn the same amount points if I arrive at the end of the timeline. This image shows, when I click to end at once
[image: Error1] and this screenshot shows when i click/slide to end of the timeline. In my unerstanding it should always spawn the same amount [image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>D3 Mapping Timeline</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="d3.slider.css" />
<style>

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

.land-boundary {
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.county-boundary {
  stroke: #ddd;
}

.site {
  opacity: 0.2;
  fill: #9cf;
}

#slider3 {
  margin: 20px 0 10px 20px;
  width: 900px;
}

svg {
  background: #eee;
}

.sphere {
  fill: rgb(92, 136, 255)
}

.land {
  fill: rgb(255, 239, 204)
}

.incident{
  fill:#07f5e7;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgb(224, 91, 49);
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}

.state {
  fill: #000;
}
.city{
  fill: #de1ae8;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
</style>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="d3.slider.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider3"></div>

<script>

var width = 1240,
  height = 720;
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale((width - 1) / 2 / Math.PI);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([3, 77])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g");

var g = svg.append("g");
var sites = svg.append("g");

svg.call(zoom)
    .call(zoom.event);

d3.json("countries.topo.json", function(error, world) {
 if (error) throw error;

  g.append("path")
      .datum({type: "Sphere"})
      .attr("class", "sphere")
      .attr("d", path);

  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.merge(world, world.objects.countries.geometries))
      .attr("class", "land")
      .attr("d", path);

  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "boundary")
      .attr("d", path);

//_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
//________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________


  d3.json("germany.topo.json", function(error, ger){
    if (error) throw error;
    var states = topojson.feature(ger, ger.objects.states),
        cities = topojson.feature(ger, ger.objects.cities );

    g.selectAll(".states")
        .data(states.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "state")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "state " + d.id; })
        .attr("d", path);
    g.append("path")
        .datum(cities)
        .attr("d", path.pointRadius('0.05'))
        .attr("class", "city");
  });
});

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  sites.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RitterLean/Slider-geojson-testing/master/vorfaelle.json", function(error, data){
    console.log(data.features[1].geometry.coordinates, "sad");
    window.site_data = data;

});


var displaySites = function(data) {
  //console.log(data)
  sites.selectAll(".site")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "site")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[1]
      })
      .attr("r", 0)
      .transition().duration(400)
      .attr("r", 0.23);
    //  "".attr""

  sites.exit()
    .transition().duration(200)
      .attr("r",0)
      .remove();
};


var dateParser = d3.time.format("%d.%m.%Y").parse;
var minDate = dateParser("01.01.2015");
var maxDate = dateParser("31.12.2015");
console.log(minDate);
var secondsInDay = 60 * 60 * 24;

d3.select('#slider3').call(d3.slider()
  .axis(true).min(minDate).max(maxDate)
  .on("slide", function(evt, value) {

    newData = site_data.features.filter(function(d){
      return dateParser(d.properties.date) < new Date(value);
    });
  console.log("New set size ", newData.length);
    displaySites(newData);
  })
);

</script>
</body>
```

Why is the slider not working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the slider was:

That you are calling the exit function on selection like this:

```
  sites.exit()
    .transition().duration(200)
      .attr("r",0)
      .remove();
```

But it should have been like this:

```
  sites.selectAll(".site")
      .data(data).exit()//remove the selection which are to be removed from dataset
    .transition().duration(200)
      .attr("r",0)
      .remove();
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BEvvVatmoH1KXpY3yHPS?p=preview)

Hope this helps!